# Kickstart 2017(apac) patterns overlap

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

i am getting incorrect output for some testcases where is my code failing.it is running correctly for most of the inputs.
here is my code
problem link https://codejam.withgoogle.com/codejam/contest/8284486/dashboard#s=p1

```
int dp[maxn][maxn];
string a,b;
int dprec(int i,int j)
{
    if(i==a.size()&&j==b.size())return 1;
    if(i==a.size()||j==b.size())return 0;
    if(dp[i][j]!=-1)return dp[i][j];
    int& k=dp[i][j];k=0;
    if(a[i]=='*'||b[j]=='*')
    {
        if(a[i]=='*')
        {
            for(int u=0;u<5;u++)
            {
                k|=dprec(i+1,j+u);
            }
        }
        if(b[j]=='*')
        {
            //k|=dprec(i+1,j);
            for(int u=0;u<5;u++)
            {
                k|=dprec(i+u,j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(a[i]==b[j])k|=dprec(i+1,j+1);
        else k=0;
    }
    return k;
}
int main()
{
    freopen("inputt.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("result.out","w",stdout);
    int t;cin>>t;
    for(int test=1;test<=t;test++){
        cin>>a>>b;
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        cout<<"Case #"<<test<<": ";
        if(dprec(0,0))cout<<"TRUE"<<endl;
        else cout<<"FALSE"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably when your 'b' is finished and there are only '*' left in 'a' because of `if(i==a.size()||j==b.size())return 0;`

Ps- I wanted to comment this but my reputation is not enough.

Comment: No that does not make difference . could you please suggest me some test case on which code is failing.

Comment: `eaa*bb
e*` gives FALSE which i think should be TRUE which means your code counts '*' of `efaa*bb` which actually shouldnt be counted. So in your loops you will have to check if character is '*' or not and take measures against it.